# How to call service methods in a widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-service, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

I have created service called BluetoothService class. In this method, I have created a method to send data to a connected Bluetooth device.
I have developed a widget home screen, it has few buttons when the user clicks this buttons **I want to send data to the Bluetooth device**. **Android doesn't allow bind services to widgets**.
I am struggling from last one week regarding this issue.

Comment: Use `startService()` to send a command to the service. Or, use an in-process event bus (e.g., greenrobot's EventBus), if the `AppWidgetProvider` and your `BluetoothService` are in the same process. Or, have the buttons use a `getService()` `PendingIntent` to trigger `startService()` calls on the service directly.

Comment: In that Service class, I am passing Bluetooth mac address to connect Bluetooth device from another activity